# How to use whole screen as button in android?

Tags: android, screen

How can i get an `onClick` response when the user touches any part of the screen?

Comment: I want the button to be invisible and yet get response from the user. Can you please help me solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a Button inside the layout manager.

and specify

```
fill_parent
```

for width and height.

and remove the border of the button.

this will work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I want the button to be invisible. I tried making it invisible by using View.GONE and View.Insivible. But when I run the program I am unable to get response from them. How can I have invisible button and yet get response from user?

Answer (score 0):

For Example you have ah `RelativeLayout`  means,

```
RelativeLayout mLyout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);
         relativeclic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 // Here do your Task
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut off the touch events before they are ever dispatched by overriding dispatchTouchEvent:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

You can get the statistics of the touch -- first, repeated, etc -- from the MotionEvent passed.